# PHP How can i copy multi files to multi folders

Tags: php

I am working with copying files, I can copy one file to multi folders, but I have problem when copying multi files to multi folders.

My code :

```
$sourcefiles = array('./folder1/test.txt', './folder1/test2.txt');

$destinations = array('./folder2/test.txt', './folder2/test2.txt');

//do copy

foreach($sourcefiles as $source) {

    foreach($destinations as $des){
        copy($source, $des);
    }

}
```

But this code not work !

Could you give me a solution :(

Thanks for any help !

Comment: You are missing the $ before source in copy();

Comment: seems like you missed a $ there at copy(source,$des)

Comment: no, i type missed $, but it is not problem:9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you currently do is looping the sourcefiles, which in the first itteration is "test.txt" and then you loop the destination array and performing the copy function 2 times:

**1st iteration with folder1/test.txt**

- copy("folder1/test.txt", "folder2/test.txt");
- copy("folder1/test.txt", "folder2/test2.txt";

**2nd iteration with folder1/test2.txt:**

- copy("folder1/test2.txt", "folder2/test.txt");
- copy("folder1/test2.txt", "folder2/test2.txt";

In the end you've overwritten both files with the last file in your $source array. So both files in "folder2" contain the data of test2.txt

What you are looking for would be:

```
foreach($sourcefiles as $key => $sourcefile) {
  copy($sourcefile, $destinations[$key]);
}
```

$sourcefile equals $sourcefiles[$key] in the above example.

This is based on the fact that PHP automatically assigns keys to your values. $sourcefiles = array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt'); can be used as:

```
$sourcefiles = array(
  0 => 'file1.txt',
  1 => 'file2.txt'
);
```

Another option is to use the length of one of the arrays in a for loop, which does the same thing but in a different way:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sourcefiles); $i++) {
    copy($sourcefiles[$i], $destinations[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Although, since we're not working with associative arrays, I'd have used a vanilla for loop rather than foreach. Still, this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is this;

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sourcefiles); $i++) {
    copy($sourcefiles[$i], $destinations[$i]);
}
```

You current code will overwrite previous copies.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have equal amount of files:

```
// php 5.4, lower version users should replace [] with array() 
$sources = ['s1', 's2'];
$destinations = ['d1', 'd2'];

$copy = [];

foreach($sources as $index => $file) $copy[$file] = $destinations[$index];


foreach($copy as $source => $destination) copy($source, $destination);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the same index for both arrays, use a `for` loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sourcefiles); $i++) {
    //In here, $sourcefiles[$i] is the source, and $destinations[$i] is the destination.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. Your nested loop is copying the files in such a way that they're bound to overwrite previous file copies. I think you need to use a simpler solution. Copying in a nested loop doesn't make any sense.

If you have the source and destination files, then I suggest a single loop:

```
$copyArray = array(
    array('source' => './folder1/test.txt', 'destination' => './folder2/test.txt'),
    array('source' => './folder1/test.txt', 'destination' => './folder2/test.txt'));

foreach ($copyArray as $copyInstructions)
{
    copy($copyInstructions['source'], $copyInstructions['destination']);
}
```

But make sure your destination file-names are different!

Comment: yes, you are right, I only want to copy files to folders, and my code make file overwrite, what can i solve this problem ?